# Updating inner text live using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, live-update

I have a project on which I am working now. In this project I want to live update some buttons text. I used `contenteditable="true"` in my project. I have 2 solutions. The first one works ok, but I don't get what I wanted in the second one has a problem. In 2nd one I want when user press a key for long time, the text will show without releasing the key.
In the first one I used `keyup` event and in the second one I used the `keydown` event. I want when the `keyup` event happens the buttons' inner text will change to the new text.

Here is my first ones code (keyup):

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).closest('.code').prev().find('a').html($(this).html());
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/xwbqpd77/).

Here is my second ones code (keydown):

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('keydown', function() {
    $(this).closest('.code').prev().find('a').html($(this).html());
})
```

[jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/a3ese3km/)

Comment: This is due to the point in the press at which each key event is raised. You cannot change it. However, if `keyup` is working as you require what is the problem?

Comment: I am not sure what you are really looking for. But you can try `input` event also.

Comment: Both fiddles are working correctly in Chrome.  But agreed with Rory, this is due to the key event.  Instead of down, why not use up or keychange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `input` event

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('input', function() {
  $(this).closest('.code').prev().find('a').html($(this).html());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of the element the user is typing in won't necessarily have updated at the time of the `keydown` event. That's why it won't update.

If you use `keyup`, you won't have that problem.